# JQGrid can't load data from JSON showing empty grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

My JQGrid code is below

```
jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid({

mtype: 'GET',
datatype: "json",
height: '350',
colNames: ['<%=Resources.Resource.Action%>','uid', '<%=Resources.Resource.Fullname%>', '<%=Resources.Resource.Username%>', '<%=Resources.Resource.Group%>', '<%=Resources.Resource.Status%>', '<%=Resources.Resource.JoinedDate%>', '<%=Resources.Resource.LastLoginDate%>', '<%=Resources.Resource.LastLoginIp%>'],
colModel: [
    { name: 'act', index: 'act', sortable: false },
    { name: 'uid', index: 'uid' },
    { name: 'userfullname', index: 'userfullname' },
    { name: 'username', index: 'username' },
    { name: 'MemberGroup', index: 'MemberGroup', editable: true },
    { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', align: "right", editable: true },
    { name: 'JoinDate', index: 'JoinDate', align: "right", editable: true, editable: true, sorttype: "date", unformat: pickDate },
    { name: 'LastLoginDate', index: 'LastLoginDate', align: "right", editable: true, editable: true, sorttype: "date", unformat: pickDate },
    { name: 'LoginIp', index: 'LoginIp', sortable: false, editable: true }],
jsonreader: {
    repeatitems: false, root: 'rootUser',
    id: 'uid',
    page:  function(obj) { return 1; },
    total: function(obj) { return 1; },
    records: function (obj) { return obj.rootUser.length; },

},
rowNum: 10,
rowList: [10, 20, 30],
pager: '#pager_jqgrid',
sortname: 'uid',
rownumbers: true,
toolbarfilter: true,
viewrecords: true,
sortorder: "asc",
gridComplete: function () {
    var ids = jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var cl = ids[i];
        be = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default btn-quick' title='Edit Row' onclick=\"showPanelPlayer()\"><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button>";
        //se = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default btn-quick' title='Save Row' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').saveRow('" + cl + "');\"><i class='fa fa-save'></i></button>";
        //ca = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default btn-quick' title='Cancel' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').restoreRow('" + cl + "');\"><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button>";
        //jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { act: be + se + ca });
        jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { act: be });
    }
},
editurl: "ajax/dummy-jqtable.html",
caption: "<%=Resources.Resource.MemberListing%>",
multiselect: true,
autowidth: true,
```

});

When I click submit button it will call my backend page and generate Json .

My Submit button code is

```
function showPanel() {                    
   var UserName = document.getElementById('txtUser').value;                   
    $('#jqgrid').setGridParam({ url: 'ListUser.aspx?cmd=LoadUser&UN=' + UserName  }).trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

The Json Return from back end is

```
{"rootUser":[{"uid":1,"userfullname":"Johnson","username":"Deng","MemberGroup":0,"Status":1,"JoinDate":new Date(1487058713667),"LastLoginDate":new Date(1487058713667),"LoginIp":""},{"uid":2,"userfullname":"James Abb","username":"James","MemberGroup":0,"Status":1,"JoinDate":new Date(1487058713667),"LastLoginDate":new Date(1487058713667),"LoginIp":""}]}
```

The problem is i facing is my grid show empty , is that anything i missing out form my code ?

Answer (score 0):

The input data are not in JSON format because of usage fields like `"JoinDate": new Date(1487058713667)`. You can validate JSON data here: http://jsonlint.com/. The fix of the problem depends on the version of jqGrid, which you use and from fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Free jqGrid for example allows to use `formatoptions: { srcformat: "u1000", newformat: "d-M-Y H:i:s" }` to parse the data from`"JoinDate": 1487058713667` to `14-Feb-2017 08:51:53`. You can use, of cause, other `newformat`.

I'd recommend you additionally never use `gridComplete` with the loop, where you call `setRowData`. The usage of custom formatter or `formatter: actions` is much more effective.

Comment: it is same not displaying anything after i remove all the datetime value

Comment: @abccba: You should provide the demo, which reproduces the problem. I tested my suggestion before posting the answer. I could see `14-Feb-2017 08:51:53` for the input data `"JoinDate": 1487058713667` for `formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: "u1000", newformat: "d-M-Y H:i:s" }`. I used free jqGrid 4.13.6 in my test.